# App icon is not showing when install flutter application,but icon showing when install release apk directly to phone

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, icons, google-play-console

I have developed a flutter application. It is a Shopping App. The application works fine. But when I download it from the play store, it shows the default icon of flutter. But when I install apk directly , The icon appears correctly as I added. What should be the problem?
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to set `uses-material-design: true` in pubspec.yaml for the icons to be included in the app

Answer (score 1):

I would need to know how did you implement the icon launcher in order to help you.

I recommend you to use this package, it will work correctly:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: It would help to include useful piece of code snippet in the case the link becomes invalid in the future